# Django get count on a ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get the total count of all **contacts** that belong to a **group**, but from within the model called **batch**....

This will help explain

**models (not shown in full)**

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    #FK
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)



class Contact(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

So within batch I want to do something like this....

```
 def get_contact_count(self):
        return len(self.group.contacts)
```

But as group has the relationship the other way around I'm struggling.

Any options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return self.group.contact_set.count()
```

Comment: +1 about to post the same, you could also set a related_name attribute on the foreignKey in your Contact model to use instead of "contact_set".

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_contact_count(self):
    return Contact.objects.filter(group=self.group).count()
```