# iterate over instance field containing multiple instances?

Tags: mysql, django

This is my fist time using django and I'm having some problems to understand how data is stored, so I can not really use it as I want to. I made many researches but I don't find any related question probably because I don't have the right keywords.

In my app model I created a WebPage and Count class:

```
class Count(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class WebPage(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    stats = models.ForeignKey(Count)
```

Then I created a `WebPage` object with multiple `Count` objects and I'd like to create a method to retrieve the sum of the `count` instances.

```
def get_clicks(self):
    self.clicks=0
    for object in self.stats:
        self.clicks+=object.count

    return str(self.clicks)
```

but I get the error `'Count' object is not iterable` which is logic because I defined `self.stats` as an single Count object. I told my self that if the `Count instances` are not stored in `self.stats` they could be stored as "global" Count instances so I iterated over the object instances `for object in self._meta.fields` but the multiple `Count` instances are missing:

```
statistics.WebPage.link
statistics.WebPage.id
statistics.WebPage.clicks
statistics.WebPage.stats
```

And I think that iterate over the "global" `Count` objects it is not an option because I could not know which `Count instance` belong to which `WebPage`.

Where the `self.stats` `Count` instances hidden? Thanks for the help!

(I'm using django 1.7)

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574821/django-get-count-on-a-foreignkey

Comment: @joelgoldstick I still struggling but the title of the question will help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your ForeignKey is the wrong way round. The model that the FK is defined in is the "many" side of the one-to-many relationship. That is, the way you have it, each Count has many WebPages, whereas I think you want the other way round.

Then you can sum the counts attached to your web page in one go via aggregation:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_clicks=my_web_page.count_set.aggregate(Sum('count'))
```

or, to get clicks for a whole queryset of webpages:

```
my_web_page_queryset.annotate(clicks=Sum('count__count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
web_page = Webpage.objects.get(pk=1)

def get_clicks(web_page):
    return web_page.contact_set.count()
```

This will work if you get a single Webpage.  If you get a group of webpages, you can loop through them and call get_clicks for each.

Comment: I can not do: `return self.contact_set.count()` and create a method instead a function? Also, by doing that I get the number of `Count` Instances isn't it? I wanted to `sum` each `count`value of the `Count` instances